# Swift slider with items

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to create list with items (similar to slider) that I can swipe left / right. I want to do it in swift.

It should look similar to this: 
[image]

Can someone advice how should I start or is there some component that allows this?

Comment: You can try add lib like this https://github.com/frederik-jacques/TNImageSliderViewController

Comment: This looks interesting. Do you have some advice how I can show "part of the image" on the sides? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at `UICollectionView`, you should be able to configure the scroll mode to 'horizontal' and adjust the cell size to what you have pictured (height should equal your screen height, and width be slightly smaller than the screen width).

You will need to implement the `UICollectionViewDataSource` on your view controller to provide the content, and the `UICollectionViewDelegate` to respond to the user scrolling to a new item, so you can animate or adjust the size of the image.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to implement it!